# Azure API Management not accessible from Browser or postman

Tags: azure, integration, azure-api-management

I have created a simple API in azure APIM which calls an azure function
the API tests fine in Azure API management test and developer portal as follows

Request URL
https://apigwdevleoper.azure-api.net/fu1/http_trigger
HTTP request
POST https://apigwdevleoper.azure-api.net/fu1/http_trigger HTTP/1.1
Host: apigwdevleoper.azure-api.net
HTTP response
Message
Trace
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 03 Dec 2023 15:31:55 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin

This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.

but when i try to access it using browswer or postman, i get following error

{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

i have enabled CORS in apim policy and also on azure function

I have call API using postman with following URL

https://apigwdevleoper.azure-api.net/fu1/http_trigg

the response is

{
"statusCode": 404,
"message": "Resource not found"
}

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access the APIM request URL in postman.

I am using the below shown Request URL.

[image]

My function is Anonymous authenticated function and in postman, I am passing **`ocp-apim-subscription-key`** key in header.

[image]

If you are getting resource not found error, I believe you need to check if your function is exist.